# query to retrieve data from sqlite by using = operator

Tags: android, sqlite

I am using a query to retrieve data from sqlite but I am getting an error.

I am using following query:

```
cursor = db.query ( TABLE_NAME, new String[] { EMPLOYEE }, USERID + " =  " + NAME, null, null, null, null );
```

Comment: Please post the error details and logcat output.

Answer (score 1):

```
db.query(TABLE_NAME, new String[] { EMPLOYEE },USERID + " = '" + NAME + "'" , null, null, null, null);
```

USERID seems to be a string type. So, the value you are comparing should be surrounded by single quote

Answer (score 0):

You can also retrieve data like this .

```
Cursor c = null;
        c = db.rawQuery("select field from tablename where field=" + your condition, null);
```